# How to extract only a particular number from HTML response

Tags: jmeter

This is how my HTML value looks like. Please note, there is a carriage return and space after q1. I only want to extract the number next to `q` as here it is 1.

```
<span id="sqa">q1
                ?</span>
```

I am using Xpath extractor, and it gives me complete value as can be seen via debug sample. The name of my variable is `answer_value`. I only wanted `1` which is a dynamic number here, not q. As only this number is used in the subsequent request.

Xpath query I am using is `//span[@id="sqa"]` and it gives me below value. I am not sure how I can split this value in Xpath or need to use a split function of JMeter to do that?

`answer_value=q1 ?`

Comment: Simply split the answer into 2 parts by using the index and get the index of number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a [Regular Expression Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-regular-expressions-extractor) and configure it to extract a number from the `answer_value` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html).

Place it below the XPath Extractor and configure like this:

[image]

You might also want to apply XPath [normalize-space() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space) to remove eventual line breaks:

```
normalize-space(//span[@id="sqa"]/text())
```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri it worked as expected. :)